# For loop gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab-ci

I have this code snippet. It gives me syntax error: unexpected end of file
If I copy it in a .sh file and run in terminal it works.

```
before_script:
    - sbt sbtVersion
    - for file in ./pending/*.sql; do
        file=$(basename "$file")
        export str_opt="$(cat ./pending/"$file"|tr '\n' ' ')"
        mv ./pending/"$file" ./done/
        done
```

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do;
```

There is no `;` after `do`. Remove it.

The way yaml in gitlab-ci works, it concatenates the lines into one long line, substituting the newline and line leading spaces for a single space:

```
for file in ./pending/*.sql; do; file=$(basename "$file"); export str_opt="$(cat ./pending/"$file"|tr '\n' ' ')"; mv ./pending/"$file" ./done/; done
```

which is invalid because of the `;` after `do`.

Script like so:

```
before_script:
    - sbt sbtVersion
    - for file in ./pending/*.sql; do
             file=$(basename "$file");
             export str_opt="$(cat ./pending/"$file"|tr '\n' ' ')";
             mv ./pending/"$file" ./done/;
        done
```

should work.

Comment: i pasted the wrong version check now. and no tis doesn't fixes it.

Comment: so its only not required after do and done because its syntax of the loop?

Comment: Well, "because its syntax" is most probably correct if I understand you correctly. The syntax of bash is that there is nothing after `do` and command list that follows. Newlines and spaces and tabs following `do` and the command list are ignored. It's not required after `done`, after `done` can be a newline also.

Comment: Ok, so to be exact: The newlines in plain scalar values inside yaml will be replaced by spaces. Let's throw some reference: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/flow/plain `Example 7.12. Plain Lines` Och, you can do empty lines too, didn't know that.

Comment: Hm. I checked some YAML to JSON converters. Three of them preserve the newlines ([1](http://convertjson.com/yaml-to-json.htm) [2](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv) [3](https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json)), one collapses whitespace ([1](https://www.json2yaml.com/)), and one says invalid YAML ([1](https://www.browserling.com/tools/yaml-to-json)).

Comment: It worked!!  Thanks :). But isn't there a new line or space after do?

 I couldn't find the documentation