# Scripting a for loop inside of a gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433852/for-loop-gitlab-ci-yml) and tried the given solution but I'm still getting various errors. This was the original bash that works fine locally:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Target directory
TARGET='C:\Users\foobar\Desktop\test'

# First create the target directory, if it doesn't exist.
mkdir -p "$TARGET/$(dirname $i)"
for i in $(git diff --name-only foo bar)
    do
        # Then copy over the file.
        cp -rf "$i" "$TARGET/$i"
    done
```

Now in my gitlab-ci.yml file it feels like I've tried 100 different variations and I'm consistently getting a "missing statement body in for loop" error.

```
package:
  stage: package
  extends: .foobar
  tags:
    - foobar
  script:
    - mkdir -p "./PACKAGE"
    - for (filename in $(git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_SHA $COMMIT_LAST_SHA)); do
        cp -rf "$filename" "./PACKAGE/$filename";
      done
    - $COMMIT_LAST_SHA = $CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

I've tried moving the semicolons around, adding additional brackets and parentheses, beginning the block script with '>', and several other solutions.